# Configure multiple ip on same vlan on centos 7 machine

Tags: centos, ip, centos7, vlan

My existing network file looks like below

```
# cat ifcfg-ens1.200
DEVICE=ens1.200
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.16.2.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
NETWORK=172.16.2.0
VLAN=yes
```

How to setup assign another ip address inside same vlan, below is what i tried but it gave errors

```
# cat ifcfg-ens1:1.200
DEVICE=ens1:1.200
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.16.1.253
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
NETWORK=172.16.1.0
VLAN=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be specified as `DEVICE=ens1.200:1`, not `DEVICE=ens1:1.200`, and the `ifcfg` filename should be set accordingly to `ifcfg-ens1.200:1`